# Age Exception error in Java

Tags: java, exception

I've created a program to ask the user to their name and age, and I've made a custom exception but it won't initiate any tips on how to make it better or how to get the exception to initiate correctly is appreciated but take note I'm still learning java.

**User-Defined Exception**: (Age Exception)

```
    package ageName;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class AgeExcpt extends Exception {

         public AgeExcpt(){     
         super("The Age you've entered is not valid");       
    }
  }
```

**Main Program**:

```
package ageName;

import java.util.Scanner;

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public class Project1 {
    public static void main(String[]args){

      Scanner age = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter your age");
      int a = age.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter you name");
      String b = age.next();

  try{  
     if(a >125 && a<0){         
        throw new AgeExcpt();
     }          
    }
    catch(AgeExcpt ex){
    System.out.println("You entered an invalid number" + a);        
    }
    finally{
        System.out.println("Your age is " + a);
        System.out.println("Your name is " + b);
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: Please format your code...

Comment: always proof-read your question: your code's all over the place, you should probably edit that (even if someone else does it for you, they shouldn't have had to)

Comment: Are you manually throwing an exception inside of a try-catch?

Comment: @AnubianNoob yes I was looking around the internet and this seemed to be the best way to do it

Comment: The expression `a > 125 && a < 0` is universally false.

Comment: You probably meant `a < 125 && a > 0`

Comment: @AnubianNoob, sorry about the formatting this is the best I can do with improper teaching I'm basically teaching myself the school fails to teach anything.

Comment: @AnubianNoob actually i want it to be false because I need it to check if it goes over 125 and it goes below zero so that it will throw my exception

Comment: @AnubianNoob He didn't mean that (I suspect), but the equivalent would be `!(a <= 125 && a >= 0)`.

Comment: You don't normally put a try just for a check. The try should be up by the start of main or at a minimum, right before you input age.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `a > 125 && a < 0` is universally false.

Comment: doesn't it need to be false? It needs to be to throw my exception to check if it doesn't go over 125 or under 0.

Comment: @MrGamma195 If it's universally false then your exception will _never_ be thrown regardless of the input.  You need to think about what you just said, namely "or".

Comment: I think I get what your telling me I need it to check if the number inputted is larger than 125 or smaller than 0 right?

Comment: @MrGamma195 Yes, "or", is the key word.

Comment: @MrGamma195 ...yes, `||` means "or".

Answer (score 2):

Below is just for your information

You Should try with (as @Jared mentioned)

```
 if(a >125 || a< 0){         
    throw new AgeExcpt();
 }
```

**The Logical Operators:**

The following lists the logical operators: u can check this link [basic operators](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm)

Examples for info

1. Operator : `&&`
   Description  : Called Logical AND operator.
   Example :If both the operands are Boolean `true`, then only the condition becomes true. (A && B) is false.
2. Operator : `||`
   Description : Called Logical OR Operator.
   Example: If any of the two operands are Boolean `true`, then the condition becomes true.(A || B) is true.

Comment: You are confusing C with Java.  In C, the expression 0 means "false" and the expression non-zero means "true", in Java it must be a boolean expression (i.e. either `true` or `false` not 0 or non-zero).

Comment: @rocks_90 the *||* operator was skimmed over along with all the other operators in my school I put them in a txt file and just had to do some searching in my computer

Comment: @rocks_90 No worries, Java programmers need to learn the C language as well--at least I think it's important.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Enter the Employee age::");
age = sc.nextInt();
try {
    if(age < 18) 
        throw new AgeException("Invalid age");
    else
        System.out.println("Valid age");
}
catch (AgeException e) {                
    System.out.println(e+"--Age must be greater than 18 !!");
    System.out.println("Please enter the correct Employee age again::");
    age = sc.nextInt();
}

what if again the age is wrong?????????
```

Comment: Please explain why this is an answer to the question.